# URI in XML digital signature

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, xml-signature, wss4j

I have this in the SignedInfo

```
<ds:Reference URI="#Id-body">
<ds:transform>
...
...
```

The whole XML file is like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
...
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-body">
<ns4:message>
...
...
</ns4:message>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am writing a Java program to calculate the digest value for digital signature. I thought following content should be hashed but I get an error saying "The prefix "**soapenv" for element "soapenv:Body" is not bound.**" So my question is, what content should be used to get digest value?

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Id-body">
<ns4:message>
...
...
</ns4:message>
</soapenv:Body>
```

My code:

```
org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
String test = "<soapenv:Body .....</sopaenv:Body>";
rawXmlBytes = test.getBytes();
Canonicalizer canon = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_WITH_COMMENTS);
byte[] canonXmlBytes = canon.canonicalize(rawXmlBytes);
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
Base64 base64 = new Base64();
String digestValue = base64.encodeToString(md.digest(canonXmlBytes));
```

Comment: Why do not you use native Java support for xml signatures or a soap library?

Comment: I need understand the whole signature process and then develop a similar library in another programming language.

Comment: Please, take a look to the standards linked here https://www.w3.org/Signature/ You will see that answering your question is not trivial